# apply the discount only on this product

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to apply a discount only on this product but I created this rule it applies to all products in the shopping cart if the product is in the shopping cart.

please help me to understand why it applies to another product.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you didn't limit the application of the discount on that particular item alone. By adding the conditions as you showed above, you are only saying 'apply this discount amount if you encounter product with SKU XXXX in cart', meaning the discount applies to all products in the cart if your cart contains the product with SKU XXXX, no matter which are the other products in the cart.

What you need is to reinforce the application of the rule to only the product with SKU XXXX in the **'Actions'** section by replicating the condition you added at *'Conditions'*. Under *'Discard subsequent rules'* you have another condition section delimited by the notice **Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items).** - that's where you have to add the new condition (as you can see, the notice is letting you know that if you leave this empty, the discount will apply to all items).

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: you are most welcome :)

Comment: can you help me with this case, please? I did what you say. now if any other rule apply in the shopping cart the label show up even the rule not apply(only the label show up)

https://i.imgur.com/1Hazjhm.png   --> shoping cart

https://i.imgur.com/6DK5xP1.png  --> the rule